# Can I rely on that when there is CBA with "i:0#.w" prefix it is always AD user?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I would like to check whether given user still exists. Since SharePoint 2013 uses Claims automatically windows users get converted to claim type. Can I rely on that user with "i:0#.w" prefix are AD users and therefore can be checked whether they still exist in AD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The prefix "i:0#.w|" is for AD users account name.If you have multiple identity providers, the other claims providers will have account name claims as **i:0ǵ.t|custom-adfs|First.Last**.

Eg: 
Windows User: **i:0#.w|stack\unnie**

Custom claimprovider:**i:0ǵ.t|stack-custom|unnie**

You can see detailed explanation of these claim format [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-20102013-claims-encoding.aspx)

Comment: Do you have any document that confirms this? Is it possible that any other provider could have the same prefix?

Comment: Check updated answer